# TypeError at /reg/ save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I created a blog app in Django 2.2. And now I have a problem with registration users. The result gave TypeError at /reg/
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert' .These are my views.py and models.py code:

````
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserOurRegistration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f"Akkaunt {username} muvaffaqiyatli ravishda yaratildi, akkauntga kirish uchun login va parolingizni kiriting")
            return redirect('user')```


And this is code of models.py:


`from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='user_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Foydalanuvchi {self.user.username} profili'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        image = Image.open(self.img.path)

        if image.height > 64 or image.width > 64:
            resize = (256, 256)
            image.thumbnail(resize)
            image.save(self.img.path)`

i tried to rewrite code 3 times, searched in the internet to solve this problem, but I can't solve it.

If you can, help me please.
````

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Answer (score -2):

Remove `form.save()` and replace it with `form.save(force_insert=False)`